# How to extract class files at runtime from a JVM

Tags: java, jvm, reverse-engineering, malware, decompiler

I have a Jar application running on my JVM. The application downloads additional `.class` files while running. Those are loaded into the memory of the application (which I verified by making a heap and thread dump). I would like to extract the class files and decompile them to see what's going on.

Does anyone know any tools for either saving the exact current state of the Jar and then decompile or the decompile (or extract `.class` files) it runtime from the JVM?

Comment: A better idea: if an application downloads and runs mystery code, and you don't have a strong reason to trust the application: DON'T RUN IT.

Comment: “the exact current state of the jar” will never change. The jar file is not affected by classes in memory. And how did you verify “by making a heap and thread dump” that there were additional classes loaded into memory?

Comment: I can see that additional packages are loaded into the memory of the JAR. A zip file is downloaded from a server, and it gets unpacked (i guess) in memory and loaded into the jar/jvm/memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JVMTI interface, you can make a so-called agent. These are invoked for each and every class file actually passed into a classloader for loading, at which point you could choose to save it.

Make a main app as normal, but instead of `psv main(String[])`, it's `public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {}`.

Make a jar with this just like you'd make a normal java runnable jar, except instead of the manifest `Main-Class` entry, it's `Premain-Class`.

Launch it as an agent (`java -javaagent:yourjar.jar -therestofyouroptionsasnormal`), and your premain will be called once, before the actual main. Then, on that instance of `Instrumentation` you so obtained, invoke `addTransformer`, passing in an instance of an implementation of `ClassFileTransformer` you write. This transformer won't actually transform anything, but its [`transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.security.ProtectionDomain-byte:A-) method will be invoked, letting you witness the class files being loaded. Save them to a directory if you want, for example.